# C++ application executes without screen output

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble making a simple 'Hello World' screen output in C++, in Code Blocks. The problem arises when I try to compile and run the code. When the code has been compiled and a console window appears, the only visible text is the following:

Process returned 1988768175 (0x768A31AF)   execution time : 0.641 s
Press any key to continue

The program terminates before I'm able to see it. I've been searching for a while now, and I haven't been able to locate what causes this. I'm using Code Block 13.12 with default settings on Windows 8.1 x64, and my code is a follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not SYSTEM("PAUSE"); ?

Comment: please search up your question online(google)

Comment: Are you sure you invoke build *and* running of your code, or are you maybe just builiding the binary? (0.64s is a bit too long for just running a hello world...)

Comment: @Bot, you shouldn't need to "pause" the system to get output.

Comment: something is wrong with his compiler...

Comment: @Bot Because of this: [system(“pause”); - Why is it wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A penny for your thoughts? While this may solve op's problem, giving some dialogue about why it's happening and why this fixes it would be nice.